# react-native-maps overlay image disappears when Zoomed in iOS

Tags: ios, react-native, overlay, react-native-maps

I am using react-native-maps (https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) library to show maps. MapType used is satellite and I have also used the overlay api to display overlay image but when I zoom in the image disappears in iOS.

I am not using pods and have installed the library manually.

**Environment Used**

```
react-native: 0.59.9
react: 16.8.3
react-native-maps: 0.25.0
```

**Expected Behavior**
The image should not disappear on zoom change

Please guide me how can I fix this issue?

Comment: Did you finally get a solution ?

Comment: @Kimako I updated files in node_modules

node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/AirMaps/AIRMapOverlay.m and node_modules/react-native-maps/lib/ios/AirMaps/ AIRMapOverlayRenderer.m 

https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/pull/3138/commits/6c90a230684db8bb6bf10c68e3fe69dc2e3456a1

I couldn't update my react-native version I also had some issues when updating the react-native-maps package so I modified the node_moulues

Comment: thanks a lot for answering to me ! :)